# Mapping excel columns with database table fields using a view when uploading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, oledb

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC4 web application which can upload data into database using excel sheets. Initially I wrote a code to import data from excel file to database. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/752981/Import-Data-from-Excel-File-to-Database-Table-in-A)  It works fine.

Now I want to map excel sheet columns with database table fields using a view. But this mapping scenario should happen after I browse & submit excel file and before data write into DB.

here the view I want to give    http://i59.tinypic.com/28uit50.png

I wish i can get any solution, suggestion or resource to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a09db79c-e4f0-48c3-89e6-74f928aff95a/column-mapping-while-importing-excel-to-sql-database-table?forum=csharpgeneral) may help you to get a solution.

Comment: thanks for the help. I couldn't find a solution by using this link.